# Help check two results of particle-bucket problems

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given $n$ particles and $N$ bucket. Buckets are allowed to be empty.

Suppose the **buckets are labeled**, then the numbers of possible outcomes are

> $N^n$ when particles are labeled
>
> $C_{n+N-1}^n$ (reads $n+N-1$ chooses $n$) when particles are unlabeled

---

Now if the **buckets are unlabeled**, are the following two counts correct? If they are right, how do we prove them? Thank you!

> $\mathop \sum \limits_{k = 1}^N C_N^k\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
>   n \\ 
>   k 
> \end{array}} \right\}$ when particles are labeled, where $\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
>   n \\ 
>   k 
> \end{array}} \right\}$ is the stirling number of the second kind. This means you first choose $k$ from the $N$ buckets to place particles (these buckets must be non-empty), with the remaining $N-k$ buckets being empty.
>
> $\frac{C_{n+N-1}^n}{N!}$ when particles are unlabeled. I get this out of intuition. I am not sure how to derive this rigorously.

Comment: $\dfrac{N^n}{N!}$ is not an integer for $N\ge 3$ so it is unlikely to be a correct count

Comment: @Henry Thank you! Yes, This one this not right

Comment: You might want to look at The Twelvefold Way (Wikipedia).

Comment: Hi guys. I updated my question. Help have a look if you have time. Thank you!

Comment: The first two parts are correct. For the third part, you just have to omit the $\binom{N}{k}$. This is because the buckets are identical so there is only $1$ way to choose $k$ buckets. For the last one, there is no explicit expression for the answer. It is usually given as $p_N(n)$ where $p_r(n)$ is the number of ways to distribute $n$ identical objects into $r$ identical boxes with empty boxes allowed.